# Shared Connection Strings in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I want to create a single connectionString in my Web.config and then re-use it in the "provider connection string" attribute of all Modules declarations.

example :
Declare a connection string this way:

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial
Catalog=MyDB;User ID=username;Password=pwd;" />
```

and then share this connection between modules:

```
<add name="Module1Context" connectionString="metadata=res//*/Module1.csdl| ... | 
...;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=MyConnectionString" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not directly possible the way you have it described above.

The solution for this is almost certainly going to be FAR more work than just copying your connection strings, commenting or uncommenting entries as you go.

Be sure you are using [Configuration Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) files to manage this.

If you really must do this, then you will need to build the connection strings yourself, using the [EntityConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) class, pulling the provider connection string from your `MyConnectionString` value. Set the EntityConnection property in your context object when you instantiate it; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896325.aspx for details.

Comment: bummer. I was hoping there was a way to not build the entity connection strings myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your connection string in runtime using ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx